# C# winform CheckListBox adding a separator

Tags: c#, winforms, checklistbox

I have a question about the CheckListBox control of WinForms. I want to add a separator bar to the List , which means I don't want to show the checkbox in this row. So, is there any resolution to this issue?

I know that ListBox can add a separator in it , but I haven't found how to do this with a CheckListBox.

THANKS!

Comment: I don't think you can do it even in a ListBox - that is, the standard WinForms ListBox control... Maybe in WPF or ASP.NET you could, but not in WinForms (which you've said you're using).